# Language dependent sorting does not work on all machines

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a piece of code like this. The AA should be sorted after Z. This is language specific for nb-NO.

Does anyone know why this does not work on every Windows PC? what do i have to install to make it work everywhere? Which settings of Windows can have an effect on the sort order?

```
var strings = new[] {"a", "AA", "z", "ZZ"}.ToList();
strings.Sort(StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("nb-NO"),false));

const string expectation = "a,z,ZZ,AA";
var sorted = string.Join(",",strings);
Console.WriteLine(sorted);
Console.WriteLine("should equal");
Console.WriteLine(expectation);

Console.WriteLine($"Success: {expectation==sorted}");
```

**Update**
On all development machines with Visual Studio installed, this worked, but not on a clean windows vm. --> now i have one vm, that has never seen a visual studio installation and it worked.

Working on development machine:
Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19041 dotnet 4.8 Locale "Germany"

Not working on
Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18063 dotnet 4.8 Locale "United States"

Comment: Where's `strings`? Also, are you *sure* it doesn't work? Perhaps `AA` was replaced *when you saved the source code* using your system's locale

Comment: why would `z` come after `a` but `ZZ` before `AA`? Is that cultural as well? (`const string expectation = "a,z,ZZ,AA";`)

Comment: @PatrickArtner the Scandinavian AA and the Turkish I are poster examples for localization quirks. That `AA` is treated as a single character. I could also mention the German `ss`. Cases like this help illustrate why people should use Unicode instead of Latin1 - especially to people from the US

Comment: Unable to reproduce your wrong sorting. Add `var strings = "z,ZZ,AA,a".Split(',').ToList();` at the top and it works.

Comment: this was compiled on in a german windows, the AA should be interpreted as Å in nb-NO and sorted after Z and before Ä at position 27 of the alphabet. The ZZ does not matter here. See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85

Comment: I'm interested to know how it could differentiate sorting for "aardvark" versus "aabenraa"... (the former should sort at the beginning of the alphabet, and the latter at the end,  in Norwegian)

Comment: .net framework but i think it's also reproducable with .net core, all on windows 10

Comment: Does http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/04/27/584439.html explain what you are seeing?

Comment: Please update your question with the **exact** versions of .NET Framework and .NET Core you are running and on which **exact** OS versions (and make it clear the results you expected for each combination, and what results you actually got). Note `10` is not specific enough. **Do not guess**.

Comment: Seems possible that this was a bug or not implemented on some versions of Windows or .Net Framework, so installing Visual Studio installs a fixed version of .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

i think this has been fixed in windows, after an update to Windows 10 2004 it works on both machines